# Trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, “Your python3 install is corrupted”

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python, 20.04, python3

Re: ["Your python3 install is corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104052/your-python3-install-is-corrupted)

None of the linked-to solution work for me when trying to update 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Wormwood 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.17
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ update-alternatives --display python
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
$ update-alternatives --display python2
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python2
$ update-alternatives --display python3
python3 - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/python3.8
  link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.6
  link python3 is /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 1
/usr/bin/python3.7 - priority 2
/usr/bin/python3.8 - priority 3
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 11 21:12 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3665768 Jul 20 08:37 /usr/bin/python2.7
$ ls -la /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3665768 Jul 20 08:37 /usr/bin/python2.7
$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.17
ls -l `which python2`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug  6  2019 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
$ ls -l `which python3`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Aug  9 21:38 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 10 21:53 /etc/alternatives/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Jul 17 05:50 /usr/bin/python3.6
$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,348 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,350 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink.
```

I don't see the problem with python[3]. Suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet) there isn't any  problem with Python 3 in 18.04, but the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 isn't ready yet.

Comment: I don't think so... the linked question seems to be why the GUI software updater doesn't prompt to upgrade to 20.04. I changed my software updater settings to Updates > Notify me of a new Ubuntu version = For any new version. Software updater now says "... However, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not available (your have 18.04)"

Are you suggesting that I should keep this setting @ LTS?

Comment: I've got the same message as you when trying to upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 because the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 isn't ready yet. It's not just you. Variations of this question about being unable to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 after the 18.04.1 point release was released have been asked 100 times at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

As commented by user Christian in [Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243673/your-python3-install-is-corrupted-please-fix-the-usr-bin-python3-symlink)