# Dependency problem with python 3 prevents all apt-get installation

Tags: apt, python3

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but got an error with Python 3 that gets corrupted (like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267534/trying-to-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04-your-python3-install-is-corrupted)). This is probably due to me changing the system Python3 (before I learnt that is bad practice, now I use virtualenv).

I tried to clean things and reinstall the original Python (Python3.6 I guess but not sure) and `python3 -V` issued Python3.6. This did not worked and I got the same corruption error as before.

I then tried to remove/reinstall python3 as suggested in some answers but I accidentally removed Python via apt-get: `sudo apt-get remove python3`, which you guessed removed lots of system parts depending on python3 (`apt-get` removes dependencies).

I ended up with a shell without graphic interface. Anyway, I successfully reinstalled what was missing (via `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) but now **`apt/apt-get/dpkg` are broken** and I cannot reinstall Python3.6 on my system (cannot upgrade to Ubuntu 20 neither).

When issuing a `apt-get/apt/dpkg` command I get tons of the following error:

```bsh
dpkg: error processing package [package_name] (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
```

and one last:

```bsh
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm currently trying to solve this issue but I fell into a rabbit hole of related issues and posts about this issue and for now none has solved mine. I tried many `apt-get` options (forcing, clean, autoremove, reinstall, `apt` instead of `apt-get`, directly `dpkg` with a force purge, etc...) without success.

I'm running out of idea (a fresh install seems to be the best option so far). Any suggestion?

---

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 64-bit

`python3 -V`: `Python 3.8.9`

`python -V`: `Python 2.7.17`

`which python3`: `/usr/bin/python3`

`find /usr/bin/python*`:

```bsh
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python3.7
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python-config
```

Comment: The fastest and simplest solution is to back up your data and clean-install 20.04. It's quite possible to tease out the conflicts and resolve them (done it many times). It might be quick...or it might be tedious (several days). Depends upon your level of skill and how badly your system is bonkered. From your description so far, seems like you are likely in the 'tedious' zone.

Comment: I edited my question to add the correct format for Ubuntu version. Concerning the Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, this is what is stated in Settings > Details > About.