# Can't upgrade to latest Ubuntu version due to corruption in Python 3's symlink

Tags: python, symbolic-link, do-release-upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. When I try to do that I got the following error:

```
Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink.
```

I've looked for solutions, and I found it can be solved by:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3 && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
do-release-upgrade
```

but when I do that I got:

```
bash: /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The output of `type -a python3; file /usr/bin/python3` is:

```
bash: type: python3: not found /usr/bin/python3: broken symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.8
```

And the output of `file /usr/bin/python3.6` is:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6: cannot open `/usr/bin/python3.6' (No such file or directory)
```

What should I do?

Comment: 18.04 should have python3.6 by default, linked to python3, so python3.8 seems like a wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-all
sudo apt purge python3.8  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager  
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Ok, no errors from that. Now, I'm trying to open software updater and it doesn't launch!

Comment: I appreciate if you can support me further.

third command got me the following error:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of update-manager:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-manager.
 update-notifier depends on update-manager-gnome | update-manager (>= 1:17.04.3); however:
  Package update-manager-gnome is not installed.
  Package update-manager is to be removed.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-manager

Answer (score 0):

User Christian commented in [Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243673/your-python3-install-is-corrupted-please-fix-the-usr-bin-python3-symlink) that `/usr/bin/python3` needs to point to `/usr/bin/python3.6`. The command you want is:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```